# OFBiz 17.2 gradlew cleanAll loadAll gives class not found exception when setup looks right

Tags: java, gradle

I am on windows 10.  I have JAVA_HOME set to my Java 11 and path includes both java and gradle 7.2.
also installed and gradle --version shows the 7.2 and java are found.

The OFBiz directory has a gradle subdirectory, settings.gradle, gradlew.bat, init-gradle-wrapper.bat, common.gradle file, and gradlew file.

trying to run gradlew.bat cleanAll loadAll in that directory fails with

C:\apache-ofbiz-17.12.08\apache-ofbiz-17.12.08>gradlew.bat cleanAll loadAll
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Trying

C:\apache-ofbiz-17.12.08\apache-ofbiz-17.12.08>init-gradle-wrapper.bat
'pwsh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

gradle wrapper --version 7.2

C:\apache-ofbiz-17.12.08\apache-ofbiz-17.12.08>gradle wrapper --version 7.2

---

### Gradle 7.2

Build time:   2021-08-17 09:59:03 UTC
Revision:     a773786b58bb28710e3dc96c4d1a7063628952ad

Kotlin:       1.5.21
Groovy:       3.0.8
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.9 compiled on September 27 2020
JVM:          11.0.12 (Microsoft 11.0.12+7)
OS:           Windows 10 10.0 amd64

C:\apache-ofbiz-17.12.08\apache-ofbiz-17.12.08>

Still gets

C:\apache-ofbiz-17.12.08\apache-ofbiz-17.12.08>gradlew cleanAll loadAll
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

In de folder "gradle" there is a file "init-gradle-wrapper.ps1"
In that file, change "pwsh" to "powershell"
Apparently , in win10, the command "pwsh" is no longer recognised.

Then run "init-gradle-wrapper.bat" again, problem should be solved.
Worked for me at least...